# :hover doesn't work with jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<ul>` where each `li` reponds on `:hover`. Here is the css:

```
.profile_nav_item:hover {
     border-color: #af0621;
}
```

But it want these borders to stay colored when I click them.

I have this jQuery function:

```
$('a[rel="tab"]').click(function(e){
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.profile_nav_item').css('border-color', 'transparent');
        $('.profile_nav_item', this).css('border-color', '#af0621');
```

But after clicking, the `:hover` css property isn't called anymore. Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zRJK9/

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Post your HTML and full CSS. We need a *complete* code example.

Comment: You just set the border style inline with javascript, and inline styles override other styles, so the `:hover` css won't work when you set other styles with javascript.

Comment: +1 for providing the fiddle. Should put some joy back in your life :)

Comment: Come on guys, this question *no longer* deserves 6 down-votes!!! (I am sure he was being sarcastic when he said "feels great to be downvoted") :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset CSS properties to '' (empty string) for the style sheet to kick in again.

```
 $('.profile_nav_item').css('border-color', '');
```

basically you are forcing the element style to `#af0621` after which the stylesheet will do nothing to override it (element styles take priority).

Passing an empty string value to `css()` removes the inline style setting.

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zRJK9/6/

Comment: Why to empty inline style where no hover effect is added with jquery the css should work, may be the OP has another problem...

Comment: @C-link Nepal: This is an assumption based on clues in the question (as the whole example is very poor). Based on new JSFiddle my assumption appears to have been correct (ish). I will fix the reversed highlight in a second)

Comment: @Anoop Joshi: Fixed now. I changed the wrong line before (PS. I hit enter on comment too soon before, hence "working" came up) :)

Comment: @Anoop Joshi: *More speed, less haste* as they say. Right fix, wrong line :)

Answer (score 1):

Because inline css attribute has more priority then included one. So when you set it with jQuery it got like this: `style="border-color: #af0621"`. Try to use `!important` in your css:

```
.profile_nav_item:hover {
     border-color: #af0621 !important;
}
```

Comment: And where did you see hover in inline style?

Comment: Avoid `!important` whenever is possible.

Comment: @C-linkNepal I did not use !important in inline css. I used for class .profile_nav_item on hover.

Comment: Thanks man it worked, but I try avoiding !important, so I'll go with the answer above.